Can a district judge leave the litigated tax issue for IRS to decide because the former doesn't have enough expertise?
Let's say I'm in a dispute with IRS about the tax they assessed on me and administrative resolution is going nowhere. I'm disputing the whole sum assessed and arguing that no tax is due period. I'm trying to choose between tax court and district court and weighing out my chances. One source I read vaguely mentioned this idea that district or any other type of court that does not specialise on tax cases, unlike the tax court, can actually refer the issue back to IRS for them to decide simply because the judge thinks that his/her court doesn't have enough expertise. Is this actually so and how frequent is it in practice?

Why are you reading sources that vaguely mention something rather than asking your lawyer?  Or at least your CPA?  Surely you aren't intending to go to court on a tax issue without representation?

@JustinCave: it's stated as a hypothetical. We presume that OP is not actually in this situation, but is posing it as a way to learn about the law, so does not have a lawyer to ask.

Notwithstanding which court you choose, you generally can’t go to court until all administrative resolution methods have been exhausted

"One source I read": Can you give a citation?


I'm trying to choose between tax court and district court and weighing out my chances.

The law doesn't change regardless of which court you use. The judge doesn't offload their job to the plaintiff or the respondent, if the judge doesn't know enough - their job is to do the research and learn, or to appoint an expert to advise them.
Tax Court decides the issue before you need to pay anything, and is usually faster and cheaper (especially with small tax cases) than a district court.
The District court will hear you after you've already paid the tax, and will decide whether you're due a refund the IRS denied.
In your specific situation (that you described here), you would probably want to hire an attorney before you even start filling any returns. The attorney will then be able to advise you on a proper course of action.

I have had a state court judge who wasn't adept at a federal tax law refer a case to a special master with more expertise on the issue to make a recommendation to the judge about how to resolve it, but never to the IRS.

The master makes recommendations, the parties submit briefs and arguments, but the judge is the one to make the decision in the end, noone else.
